# Why does this C program give me an missing integer from an For loop?

Tags: c

I am trying to get the value of "w" but when I do the For loop ,it only gives me 4 results:

Problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyRMa.jpg

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int x,e,w;
    float a = 2.5;
    for (x=1; x<6; x++) {
        if (x>a) {
            w = x*cbrt(x-a);
        } 
        else if (x=a) {
            w = x*sin(a*x);
        }
        else if (x<a) {
            w = pow(e,(-a*x))*cos(a*x);
        } 
        printf("%d ",x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 4 5
```

I know in this program i dont search for the value of w but I wanted to see why does it give me only 4 number instead of 5? why is the one missing and ow can I solve it? Thank you

Comment: `if ( x = a )`.

Comment: i did that , is there a problem with it?

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: ouuuu, i get it now , thank you very much it works now , Ihope you have an wonderfull day!

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings, if possible make them errors, and fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`else if (x=a)` should be`else if (x==a)`